# Dynamic range that stops at the number before the last zero in a column

Tags: excel

I have been trying to create a dynamic range within excel that would include all the rows in a column up until the last number before all the zeroes. For example here is the string of data.

0
0
350
500
107
0
200
500
27
736
0
0
0
0

In this case the numbers within the range that would be selected would be:

0
0
350
500
107
0
200
500
27
736

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thx

Comment: Are you comfortable with using VBA, because you are mostly likely going to need it for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your data starts at `A1` on `Sheet1` you could define the range by using this formula in the "refers to" box

`=Sheet1!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,MATCH(2,1/(Sheet1!$A:$A>0)))`

that will include all the data up to the last >0 value

Comment: Shorter and faster than me!  +1

Comment: this one is very sweet Barry!, i'm trying to figure out how do you find out the last group of zeroes and then go up from there...

Comment: I've been studying this and see how it works now.  It's great!  One small note, you'd want "<>0" if there is a possibility of negative numbers and you want to include them.

Comment: @macutan - it doesn't actually find the last group of zeroes, the MATCH function, i.e. MATCH(2,1/(Sheet1!$A:$A>0)) finds the position of the last value >0 (and you can make it <>0 to include negatives if required, as per Doug's suggestion) and that becomes the end point of the range

Comment: I tried this last night on excel 2010 and it worked, but i'm trying it in excel 2003 but it is not working.. any workaround to make it work in excel 2003?

Comment: I can't test right now but I believe that the MATCH part would need a specific range in Excel 2003 rather than the whole column, so for instance assuming up to 1000 rows of data try =Sheet1!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,MATCH(2,1/(`Sheet1!$A$1:$A$1000`>0))) adjust as required

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a header row and data starts in A2:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,2):INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,(SUMPRODUCT(MAX((Sheet1!$A:$A<>0)*ROW(Sheet1!$A:$A)))))
```

Comment: One thing to note about the above is that it works if Row 2 is deleted, because of the first index statement.